# How to record/capture voice/video for Vaadin application

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am starting to play around Vaadin framework for my project. 
The goal is to have simple functionality to record voice or if possible video and later on save in an SQL database.

What I would like to know how do I create new components for this? Is there already component available that I can use for simple recording?

I found Audio and Video classes, but they are for playback.There are no add-ons (Vaadin site) I am aware of that takes care of this. The java libraries I found will only record in the server side (where the app lies). Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't already built-in ways for this goal, and it was a really tricky one in the past year in general for a web developer.

Best shot is to develop your own add-on based on the new media HTML5 functionalities.
A good start could be this
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
and for vaadin this chapter and following
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.javascript.html